# Show a null in my Toast

Tags: android, stringbuilder

I am newbie in `Android` developing, I run my very simple app but my `Toast` shows a `null`. I check my connection and `192.168.1.37/get_cat.php` is correct in my browser. I think all on the server is correct and worked properly. Following my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String line;
private String json;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Json_print();
    Toast.makeText(this, json, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void Json_print() {

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.37/get_cat.php");
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                connection.setReadTimeout(10000);

                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }

                json = stringBuilder.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("tag", e.toString());
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();



}
```

Comment: You are starting async thread and when your toast is shown your task is not completed

Comment: I think your missing a `HttpUrlConnection.connect()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting `async` operation and when your toast is shown that task is not completed yet and `json` field is still `null`

Try this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String line;
private String json;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Json_print();
}

private void Json_print() {

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.37/get_cat.php");
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                connection.setReadTimeout(10000);

                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }

                json = stringBuilder.toString();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, json, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
                });

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("tag", e.toString());
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: @pulp_fiction you are not right. If you make some ui operation from non-ui thread you will receive `CalledFromWrongThreadException`

Answer (score 0):

The field `json` is null because your network call is happening in another thread. When you call `Json_print()` the code does not wait for the code inside the `Thread` you created to complete and the `Toast` call is made immediately.

Instead, put your `Toast` call inside a function like so:

```
private void showToast() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(this, json, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Call this function at the end of your background `Thread` that makes the network request. Make sure the call to the function is inside your `Thread` `run` function. Note the importance to make sure that it is run on the main UI thread, it will crash if not run on the UI thread.